# Getting started with a custom JXTA PeerGroup

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

I have been working with *JXTA* 2.3 for the last year or so for a peer-to-peer computing platform I am developing. I am migrating to *JXTA* 2.5 and in the process I am trying to clean up a lot of my use of *JXTA*. For the most part, I approached *JXTA* with a **just make it work** attitude. I used it to jumpstart creating and managing my peer-to-peer overlay network and providing basic communication services. I would like to use it in a more *JXTA* way since I am making changes to move to 2.5 anyway.

My first step would be a basic creation of a custom `PeerGroup`. I see some new new mechanisms that are using the `META-INF.services` infrastructure of Java. Should I be listing a related `PeerGroup` implementing object here with a *GUID* in `net.jxta.platform.Module`? As I understand it, if I do this, when a group with a spec ID matching the *GUID* is encountered and joined or created it should automatically use the matching object. I should be able to just manually tie a `PeerGroup` object to the group but this new method using `META-INF` seems to be a lot easier to manage.

Does anyone have any pointers or examples of using this infrastructure for `PeerGroup` implementation? Also, some general information on the `META-INF.services` mechanism in Java would be helpful.

Comment: The Practical JXTA II book has been made available for reading on Scribd. You will find answer to your question in there. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

The `META-INF.services` stuff is known by its class name in the API: [ServiceLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). A Google search for [ServiceLoader](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=ServiceLoader) yields some information.

I am not really familiar with it, but sometimes it's all about knowing the right search keywords.